# Unity3D is not loading this .NET library, with no obvious reason why

Tags: c#, dll, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a third party SDK working with Unity. Here's a download of the files in said SDK: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11217331/VSDK.zip

The "_DotNET.dll" is a .NET wrapper for the unmanaged code in the CPP dll. For some reason, Unity doesn't load the .NET dll whatever I try:

- I put both DLLs in the Assets/Plugins folder
- I am using Unity Pro 4.5.0f6, on Windows 8.1
- The SDK "_DotNET.dll" is x86 .NET 2.0, and seems to be completely compatible with Unity's version of Mono
- I tried putting both DLLs in the Program Files/Unity/Editor folder, still doesn't load them
- I do not have the source to these DLLs so I can't make any changes to them, but everything points at Unity being weird here
- There are no errors in the editor log or anywhere that give me a hint to why Unity just completely ignores these DLLs

If you can get this C# script working in Unity by loading these DLLs, please tell me your secrets:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using ViconDataStreamSDK;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    ViconDataStreamSDK.DotNET.Client e;

    void Start () {
        bool isConnected = e.IsConnected().Connected;

        Debug.Log("Is it connected?: " + isConnected.ToString());

    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I can load it by going back one Unity version, to 4.3.4f1. No idea why, culprit must be somewhere in the Unity 4.5 patch notes (http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.5).

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to put the source code for the C# plugin into the unity and see what actual errors it gives you.